# 2-Frobenius Groups of order 25920

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

A group $G$ is called a 2-Frobenius group if $G=ABC$, where $A$ and $AB$ are normal subgroups of $G$, $AB$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $A$ and complement $B$ and $BC$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $B$ and complement $C$.

Let  $A$ be a nilpotent group of order $2^4.3^4=1296$ and order $B$  equal to $5$ and order $C$ equal to $4$. So we know that $BC$ is the only Frobenius group of order $20$. Now, I would like to know that whether we can find all such 2-Frobenius group $G=ABC$ of order 25920?
Actually I am interested in finding $Irr(G)$ as well. (Irr(G) is the set of irreducible characters of group $G$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest dimensional modules for a cyclic group of order $5$ over both ${\mathbb F}_2$ and ${\mathbb F}_3$ have dimension $4$, so $A$ must be a direct product of elementary abelian groups of orders $2^4$ and $3^4$. Also, $BC$ has a single faithful $4$-dimensional module over both ${\mathbb F}_2$ and ${\mathbb F}_3$, so there is a unique $2$-Frobenius group $ABC$ of the type you describe.

You get $2$-Frobenius groups $A_1BC$ and $A_2BC$ as the semidirect product of these two irreducible modules with $BC$, where $|A_1|=2^4$, $|A_2|=3^4$, and $ABC$ is a subdirect product $(A_1 \times A_2)BC$ of $A_1BC$ and $A_2BC$. Hence $ABC$ has an intransitive permutation representation of degree $97$.

You should probably use GAP (or Magma) to compute the character table of $ABC$. It has $111$ conjugacy classes.

Comment: Thanks a million for your great answer. But actually I do not know how I can introduce this group to GAP or Magma. Actually I would like to know the orders of vanishing element of $G$. ($g\in G$ is a vanishing element of $G$, if there exsits $\chi\in Irr(G)$ such that $\chi(g)=0$)

Comment: If it's any help, the groups $A_1BC$ and $A_2BC$ are SmallGroup(320,1583) and SmallGroup(1620,421), so you just need to define the correct subdirect product.

Comment: Since $G$ is a subdirect product $A_1BC$ and $A_2BC$, it is a subgroup of $A_1BC\times A_2BC$. So I have used the following commands in GAP to achive $G$:                                                                        `gap>A1BC:=SmallGroup(320,1583);;
A2BC:=SmallGroup(1620,421);;
gap> K:=DirectProduct(A1BC,A2BC);;
gap> L:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(K);;          
   gap>L:=Filtered(L,x->Order(Representative(x))=25920);`  
  Now I can access to all subgroups of $A_1BC\times A_2BC$ of order $2^6.3^4.5$. But as I have checked non of them have 111 conjugacy classes.

Comment: Sorry about that - it was too late at night!  $A_1BC$ is SmallGroup(320,1635); Have another go!

Comment: Thanks a million. It works!